# How to get this complementary form of derangement written in a Wikipedia article?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), how do they get the complementary form of

$$\Big|S\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\Big|=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\alpha_k$$

from $$\Big|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\Big|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\alpha_k$$

The thing that confuses me is that we don't know what is $|S|$, do we even need to know it?

Could someone please clarify the steps or reasoning needed to get that complementary form?

It is not explicitly written in the article the steps that they took.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Well it states that $S$ is the universal set. If you do "find" on the page you will see that a little higher up they define $S$ as a finite set containing the union of all the $A_i$.

Comment: You can let the bars adjust to their content by using `\left` and `\right` instead of `\Big` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left|S\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right|=|S|-\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right|=\alpha_0-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\alpha_k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\alpha_k\;.$$